# Water coming back into the dishwasher?

Tags: plumbing

I just installed a new dishwasher, replacing an old one.  Everything is working properly, but the problem I'm having is, after it has ran it's cycle and drained out and done and clean, after about 4 - 6 hours sitting there is water that has drained back into the dishwasher.

Comment: Describe how the drain pipes are connected, or even better upload a picture of the drain plumbing. There should be an air gap or "high loop".

Answer (score 1):

Many dishawshers will have a small amount of water left in the bottom of the cabinet after the cycle has run - but it shouldn't be much. One thing you should check is to make sure your drain line goes up into an air gap valve at the sink.
If you haven't installed an air gap you should at least take the drain line from the DW up into a high loop before it terminates in the disposal or drain line. A high loop means running it up to just under the countertop. This is especially important if it drains into the disposal. The high loop uses gravity to keeps waste from the disposal from backing up into the DW.